# Can't connect to mainnet using web3.py and IPC provider

Tags: python, ipc, web3py, go-ethereum

```
from web3 import Web3

web3 = Web3(Web3.IPCProvider())
print(web3.isConnected())
web3.eth.get_balance('some_adress')
```

isConnected returns True but does not get my balance correctly(always returns 0).
I'm using geth and also used the `get attach` command on ipc:.\pipe\geth.ipc